# How do I fix a missing command whose package is already installed?

Tags: apt, package-management, wine, dpkg

I have found that other have had this problem, but none of their solutions have solved my own. Since I cannot embed images, (I don't have 10 reputation yet) you will have to be satisfied with this:

```
isaac@isaac-HP-EliteBook-840-G1:~$ sudo apt-get install winetricks
[sudo] password for isaac: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
winetricks is already the newest version (0.0+20141009+svn1208-2ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 131 not upgraded.
isaac@isaac-HP-EliteBook-840-G1:~$ whereis winetricks
winetricks:
isaac@isaac-HP-EliteBook-840-G1:~$ winetricks
The program 'winetricks' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install winetricks
isaac@isaac-HP-EliteBook-840-G1:~$ sudo apt install winetricks
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
winetricks is already the newest version (0.0+20141009+svn1208-2ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 131 not upgraded.
isaac@isaac-HP-EliteBook-840-G1:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 131 not upgraded.
```

Does anybody have any idea of new things that I haven't tried? My mirror is the correct one and I have previously used wine/winetricks, but My new wine install 
has been working perfectly fine and winetricks doesn't appear to have any leftover packages still on my PC.

Comment: Sometimes `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo updatedb` helps in similar issues.

Comment: Try with 

    `which winetricks`

Check is it installed:

    `dpkg -l | grep winetricks`

Comment: I don't know anything about `winetricks`, but often this kind of situation is caused by manually deleting system files (so that the package management system doesn't know they're gone) and is often solved by **re**-installing the package `sudo apt-get install --reinstall winetricks`

Comment: upon trying SpasSpasov 's solution I was met with `updatedb: unexpected operand on command line`  when I tried  @MilosM's  `dpkg -l | grep winetricks` I was given some wierd spacing, but some information nonetheless: `ii  winetricks                                  0.0+20141009+svn1208-2ubuntu1                 all          Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer (winetricks)` luckily, I didn't have to use any of this information because @steeldriver 's solution worked like a charm. Thank you all for the help, this case is now closed :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem relatively easily with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall winetricks`. Thanks to @steeldiver for providing the solution